# How to invert a black & white video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, color

I have here a video. I wish to make the white background black and black font white. How do I do that? [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use the curves modifier

The **curves modifier** can be found in the **video sequence editor**.
Inverting the pixels is easy by changing the shape of the curve(s). The left point (representing the darkest pixels) originally at 0 should be set to 1 (to map those pixels to be the brightest) and vice versa the right curve point from 1 to 0.
Here is a gif:
[image: inverting BW image]

This gif only shows the work for the C-channel (luminance) which is enough for inverting a B&W-video. Note that you have do the same for the R-, G- and B- channels if you also want to invert the colors.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a star. 